# Request.getParameter() method not working

Tags: jsp

I am creating a website and am having trouble in retrieving value from textbox. I am having a login page in which user inputs username. I have to take the value from textbox and then send it to `login.jsp` where `request.getParameter()` method takes the value of textbox.  But i guess `request.getParameter()` is not working.Please help me in pointing mistake.
Here is My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .center{
            margin: auto;
            width: 400px; 
            height: 400px;
            border: 3px;
            padding-top: 50px;
        }


    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="center" >
        <form action="login.jsp" method="post">
            <div>
                <img src="images/crms.png" style="padding-bottom:50px;" width="440" height="240">
            </div>
            <div id="comment_bubble" >
                <div class="form" id="form1">
                    <h2 style="padding-left:125px;">Sign In</h2>
                    <img src="images/hooo.png" style="padding-left:120px;padding-bottom:10px; ">
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Username" name="inputtext" value=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback " id="username"></span><br></div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder=" Password" align="center" name="pwd" value=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback" id="pass"></span><br></div>
                    <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="submit" onclick="callfun();" >Submit</button><br><br>
                    <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" id="Register">Create a new account</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                        <h3>Create A New Account</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group" id="form2">
                            <label for="sel1"> Designation</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1" >
                                <option>Director</option>
                                <option>Faculty</option>
                                <option>Technician</option>
                            </select><br>

                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"><br>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Faculty_Id"><br>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"><br>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Re-type password"><br>

                            <button id="button2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button> 

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script>
        function callfun() {
            location.href = "login.jsp";
        }
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

and here is my Jsp code:

```
 <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.*,java.util.*"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
 <%
String userid = request.getParameter("inputtext");
if(userid==null){
out.println("userid missing");
}
else{
String pass = request.getParameter("pwd");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crms", "root", "root");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from login where username='" + userid + "'");

if (rs.next()) {
    if (rs.getString(2).equals(pass)) {
        String site=new String("complain.jsp");
        response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
        response.setHeader("Location",site);
    } else {
        out.println("else running");
    }
}
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your password input field password have a name and you can get the password value by the name. Say for example

```
<input type="password" value="" name="pass">
```

your can get the value form backend by calling

```
String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
```

Anyways to get the parameter value, you should submit (post) the form with a specific url. Can you include an id for your form

```
<form action="login.jsp" method="post" id="myForm">
```

And your script should be

```
<script>
        function callfun() {
            $("#myForm").submit();
        }
</script>
```

And let me know, if that works.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help. but its still not displaying the username.

Comment: When you fetch problem? Creating new account or login?

Comment: Here i see your `<form>` tag end not enclosing the `Create new Account`. so for creating new account. Enclose your  `</form>` tag after all input field.

Comment: I have enclosed my form tag at the end of div tag and above the modal of  create new account. My create new account code doesnot have anything to do with login code, Ps Thanx for help. :)

Comment: Anyway I tried enclosing </form> tag after all input field. Still not working

Comment: Did you adjust also javascript? also change your submit button to `<input id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="callfun();" value="Submit" />`. let put the handle to javascript `callfun()` method to post the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<form action="login.jsp" method="POST">`, then you don't need any javascript to send data to jsp. Just use

```
 <button id="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

The `submit` type take care of sending data to next screen

Answer (score 0):

Your password field doesn't have a name, so `request.getParameter()` can't find it. It should be

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pwd">
```

You're doing this wrong anyway. You should `select * from login where username = ? and password = ?`, and see if there are any results. Let the database do the work.

Comment: if he did this, i think it doesn't work. because he end `<form>` tag not enclosing those input field. of course name should be added. thanks for your negative vote.

Comment: I am having trouble in getting value in userid variable(login.jsp). the value in userid variable is always null whatsoever i may do. when i compiling and running my program it always print userid missing.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna There is no 'end `<form>`' tag in this answer, or in yours either for that matter, but as he is submitting via Javascript it isn't relevant. I would agree that he shouldn't do that, but it isn't the actual problem. This is. You don't have any information about voter identity, and guesswork about it is both pointless and improper.

Comment: @EJP I agree with you & teach me if i'm wrong. Anyways  I run the code in spring mvc just to see if i missed anything from frontend side, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I gave `name` tag to all the fields and read the values using the same in `request.getParameter()` method. Apparently, removing the `enctype="multipart/form-data` declaration in `<form>` field fixed the issue.